# Запускается копия Activity

Tags: android, activity, usb

Реализовал открытие моего приложения при подключении USB устройства.

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
```

Возникла проблема:

1. Подключаю usb устройство, открывается мое приложение все работает корректно.
2. Отключаю устройство, приложение оповещает о разрыве соединения, activity запущен, все работает корректно.
3. Подключаю устройство, открывается копия activity, старый activity уходит в фон, что приводит к ошибке в логике работы моего приложения.

Отсюда вопрос:

Как сделать, чтобы при повторном подключении usb устройства не открывался новый экземпляр моего приложения, а приходила информация в уже запущенный?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого есть специальный атрибут манифеста.
К примеру, если у вас всего одна активити, достаточно будет так:

```
<activity ..
  android:launchMode= "singleTop" />
```

При повторном подключении будет вызываться метод `onNewIntent()`

Если ситуация сложнее, изучите все возможности (`singleTask`, `singleInstance`).
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Невнимательно читал документацию, потому проглядел флаги.

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте флаг `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` к активити в манифесте. Это предотвратит создание новой активити, если один её экземпляр уже есть в стеке.

И ловить новый интент в методе `onNewIntent()`.  Подробнее о флагах запуска для активити читайте в [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте отключать приложение когда отсоединяете USB кабель:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
    android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" 
    android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
```